# An Olympiad Geometry question; Trigonometry.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math

Well, for reference, I was solving this;

Let ABC be a triangle with sides $ 51, 52, 53$. Let $Ω$ denote the incircle of $\Delta ABC$. Draw
tangents to $Ω$ which are parallel to the sides of $\Delta ABC$. Let $r_1, r_2, r_3$ be the inradii of the three
corner triangles so formed. Find the largest integer that does not exceed $r_1 + r_2 + r_3$.

*Source*; **Stage 1 of India MO.**

There was this example in my book ; [image]

so I knew $\frac{r_1}{r_i}$ (where $r_i$ is the inradius of of $\Delta ABC$ is $\tan^2(\frac{\pi - A}{4})$ and so on.

So $r_1 + r_2 + r_3$ = $r_i$$[\tan^2(\frac{\pi - A}{4})$ + $\tan^2(\frac{\pi - B}{4})$ + $\tan^2(\frac{\pi - C}{4})]$ and I can easily calculate $r_i$, so all I need is the whole tangent sum.

But I don't know how to compute that,

So I need help in computing the sum of those tangents,

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks!

EDIT; So if anyone could please tell me If $x_1+x_2+x3=\pi/2$, then what is $\sum{x_i}^{3}tan^2x_1$ that would be great too, thanks

Comment: let me guess the screenshot is from  the pathfinder book no?:)

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore , it is, i thought the screenshot would be better for the eyes as compared to a photo of the hardcopy, hence i attached the screen shot; anyways, do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore but here; isn't the exradius the inradius of $\Delta ABC$?, and we already know what it is.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore , thanks, i did solve it using $_1$=$\frac{Δ}{−}$ and similarity,

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore i have one question; If $x_1+x_2+x3=\pi/2$, then what is $\sum tan^2x_1$

Comment: glad to help,about your last comment can you elaborate your question more  ,As far as i can see the sum need not have a definite value

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore oh yes, i'm sorry, i thought that would have a constant value as i got $r_1+r_2+r_3 = R_i$ using your method, so thanks again!

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore i have one more question, have you solved the book too?

Comment: nope ,I only did the inequality part for fun and havent done any other chapter